# Return variable from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can`t return result of this function.

```
function get_duration() {
    var a = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=3KMz3JqRByY&max-results=50& format=5,1,6",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            re2 = /seconds='(\d+)'/ig;
            while (re.exec(data) != null) {
                a = re2.exec(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Use `return` inside the `success` callback

Comment: It has to do with the fact your AJAX call is asynchronous, your question has also been asked (and answered) a million times, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?lq=1).

Comment: use `async = false` in your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `return` inside the `success` callback since, **A** in Ajax is **asynchronous**.

Like this:

```
function get_duration() {
    var a = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=3KMz3JqRByY&max-results=50& format=5,1,6",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            re2 = /seconds='(\d+)'/ig;
            while (re.exec(data) != null) {
                a = re2.exec(data);
            }
            return a;
        }
    });
}
```

But, this function isn't guaranteed to return. You'll have to use a callback function kind of thing.

Comment: Note `get_duration()` still returns `undefined` this way.